# data entry lost in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have php form submission code to enter data into phpmyadmin. While I try to executed my code, I see my data was inserted into my table. But when I reload my browser (I'm using chrome and mozilla, and I cleared coockies of both chrome and mozilla), I lost my data in my table.

My problem is what is causing my data lost in my table? is there any problem with my code or there is any problem in server?

note: I worked online, not on my local server (XAMPP)

and here is my code:

```
// Insert
if ($menu=='news' AND $submit=='input'){
$file_loc    = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']
$file_type   = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
$file_name   = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$rand        = rand(1,99);
$unique_file = $rand.$file_name;


// If any image uploaded
if (!empty($file_loc)){
if ($file_type != "image/jpeg" AND $file_type != "image/pjpeg"){
echo "<script>alert('Upload failed. Be sure your image is JPEG
format.');window.history.go(-1);</script>"; 
} else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, category_name, news_content, date, time, image) VALUES ('$_POST['title']', '$_POST['category_name']','$_POST['news_content']', '$date', '$time', '$_POST['tag']', '$unique_file')");
    header('location:../../media.php?menu='.$menu);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any advice and guidance

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you as long as you don't provide the relevant code

Comment: You're not "inserting into phpmyadmin"! phpMyAdmin is not your database. MySQL is. phpMyAdmin is only a graphical tool making it easy to see what's in your database.

Comment: @jomblo paste your code in order to help you. About phpmyadmin, it is just a front end, I mean, this is a tool you for manage your database,  my questions is about how you are using the phpmyadmin, remember is just a frontend, and probably you just doing changes on queries, for exmaple just edit result, but it is not been saved on database. But if you are writing an application that is saving something and you see it is being savin on table on myadmin, and when you reload the page that you ceate there is no result, probably you have a reset table line in your code

Comment: Updated question. I provided my code. Thanks a alot to @GeraldSchneider and Carlos :)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

Comment: [The fine manual tells you everything that's wrong with `mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php): *Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.*

Comment: Hi Guillaume Poussel, excuse me to ask you where is that vulnerable located? :)

Comment: @jomblo See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Here's the vulnerability explained: http://bobby-tables.com Please learn from `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--`

Comment: To Carlos:
After inspected that code, could you tell me what is causing data lost when I reload my browser? I'm sure that before I reload my browser, my data wes entered in the table